# No puedo copiar documentos de un directorio a otro

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Estoy empezando con un proyecto en Angular 4 y utilizare un template descargado de una pagina, pero cuando trato de copiar las carpetas que vienen dentro de assets no me deja copiarlas en el otro directorio, de hecho no me deja ni crear una carpeta nueva. El proyecto de angular (carpeta en la que no me deja copiar nada) la cree en modo root, no se si eso tenga algo que ver, ¿que puedo hacer para que pueda copiar y hacer cosas sin problemas? Estas es una imagen de los permisos que tienen ambas carpetas, la de la izquierda es el proyecto angular y la de la derecha la carpeta del template Estas es una imagen de los permisos que tienen ambas carpetas, la de la izquierda es el proyecto angular y la de la derecha la carpeta del template

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si la carpeta lo has creado como root, entonces esa carpeta requiere los mismo persmisos que root, y si lo quieres hacer como un usuario normal no lo podras hacer, tienes que hacerlo como root, o cambia el usuario y los permisos de esa carpeta.

Comment: ¿Te valió la explicación? Si es así, por favor, acepta una de las respuesta como respuesta de la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es precisamente lo que comentas. Has creado la carpeta como `root` y por tanto solamente ese usuario puede hacer modificaciones o alteraciones en ese directorio y todo sus hijos.

Lo que deberias de hacer es crear siempre todos los directorios con el usuario del sistema que tengas.

En este caso, como `root` lo que debes de hacer es lo siguiente.

`chown -R miusuario:miusuario /mi/ruta/micarpeta`

De esta manera lo que estas haciendo es cambiar el usuario y grupo de ese directorio. De manera que ya podrías editar y modificar esa carpeta.

Si no sabes cual es tu usuario del sistema puede ejecutar lo siguiente:

`whoami`

Answer (score 0):

Me imagino que debes de darle permisos a esa carpeta por consola, con chmod.. Salu2.

Comment: Hola reyesg93, esta respuesta ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad. Aunque puede que sirva al usuario, deberías añadir más detalles a la respuesta en sí: ¿qué es lo que hace `chmod` y por qué resolvería el problema?¿cómo debería ejecutarlo el usuario para que le funcione? Te recomiendo que leas [answer] en el centro de ayuda donde encontrarás consejos para mejorar la respuesta. Saludos.